# Can I upgrade node version of existing angular project without upgrading anything else

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

Currently node version in angular project and in global is 14.17.0 and **@angular/cli version is 11.2.14** . Can I upgrade only node version to 17.9.0 without upgrading @angular/cli, Is it possible ?

```json
{
  "name": "test-pro",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "A angular 6+ directive for adding autocomplete functionality to text input elements, built around composability",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 14.17.0",
    "npm": ">= 6.14.13"
  },
  ....
```

Comment: `npm install -g n` > `n 17.9.0` ? :)

Comment: @SebastienServouze, thanks for quick response, Could you please confirm me, Can I upgrade only node version to 17.9.0 without upgrading @angular/cli ?

Comment: You should be able to, the version difference only changed so much. No promises but jumps like this can sometimes cause issues with other modules just troubleshoot after if necessary easy enough. I anticipate 10-30 minutes if any issues to fix them.